# React - laravel - Uncaught Error: Target container is not a DOM element

Tags: javascript, reactjs, laravel, webpack, laravel-mix

I'm using React as frontend to my laravel project. My React components are rendering as expected but I'm constantly getting this error in the chrome devtool console:

```
Uncaught Error: Target container is not a DOM element.
  at invariant (app.js:38102)
  at legacyRenderSubtreeIntoContainer (app.js:56749)
  at Object.render (app.js:56830)
  at Object.<anonymous> (app.js:58393)
  at __webpack_require__ (app.js:20)
  at Object.<anonymous> (app.js:13977)
  at __webpack_require__ (app.js:20)
  at Object.<anonymous> (app.js:13951)
  at __webpack_require__ (app.js:20)
  at app.js:63
```

I looked all over the internet and I didn't find a solution that solves this.
Do you know what's causing this?

I put my `<script type="text/javascript" src="{{ asset('js/app.js') }}"></script>`
before the closing `</body>` tag.

here is my Sidebar.js component:

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom'

const Sidebar = () => (
<div className="sidebar" data-color="purple" data-background-color="white" data-image="../assets/img/sidebar-1.jpg">
    <div className="logo">
        <a href="http://www.creative-tim.com" className="simple-text logo-normal">
        Creative Tim
        </a>
    </div>
    <div className="sidebar-wrapper">
        <ul className="nav">
        <li className="nav-item active  ">
            <a className="nav-link" href="./dashboard.html">
            <i className="material-icons">dashboard</i>
            <p>Dashboard</p>
            </a>
        </li>
        <li className="nav-item ">
            <a className="nav-link" href="./user.html">
            <i className="material-icons">person</i>
            <p>User Profile</p>
            </a>
        </li>
        <li className="nav-item ">
            <a className="nav-link" href="./tables.html">
            <i className="material-icons">content_paste</i>
            <p>Table List</p>
            </a>
        </li>
        <li className="nav-item ">
            <a className="nav-link" href="./typography.html">
            <i className="material-icons">library_books</i>
            <p>Typography</p>
            </a>
        </li>
        <li className="nav-item ">
            <a className="nav-link" href="./icons.html">
            <i className="material-icons">bubble_chart</i>
            <p>Icons</p>
            </a>
        </li>
        <li className="nav-item ">
            <a className="nav-link" href="./map.html">
            <i className="material-icons">location_ons</i>
            <p>Maps</p>
            </a>
        </li>
        <li className="nav-item ">
            <a className="nav-link" href="./notifications.html">
            <i className="material-icons">notifications</i>
            <p>Notifications</p>
            </a>
        </li>
        <li className="nav-item ">
            <a className="nav-link" href="./rtl.html">
            <i className="material-icons">language</i>
            <p>RTL Support</p>
            </a>
        </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
    )

if(document.getElementById('sidebar')) {
    ReactDOM.render(<Sidebar />, document.getElementById('sidebar'))
}

export default Sidebar;
```

Comment: share your code also

Comment: @ShaielndraGupta checkout the code.

Comment: Does your html have a #sidebar?

Comment: @PlayMa256 yeah it has #sidebar that's why the component is rendered. But I don't know the origine of the error

Comment: can you show where have you write `<script src="{% static "build/react.js" %}"></script>` in your code

Comment: @ShaielndraGupta I'm not using this tag where should I use it in my code?

Comment: inside your body

Comment: I've put it before <script type="text/javascript" src="{{ asset('js/app.js') }}"></script> but it didn't make difference. Nothing changed

Answer (score 0):

Can you please check that your main component#render function is returning one DOM element ... ( try to wrap all the returning components in one

Comment: thanks :) ! Everything was good in my components the problem was due to some js files my template was depending on. Problem solved !

Answer (score 0):

Its telling you that it cannot find this `'sidebar'` which you speak of. Conventionally, unless you tweaked your `index.html` which should be in your `public/index.html` if you used `create-react-app` or in the main root folder if you are still using `npm init`.

Your top level div I will bet, unless you changed it, has a class of container:

```
<div class="container"></div>
```

Thats a really good location to render your component to. In most React apps you will see this, a body tag and a div with a class of container or maybe app.

All the components you create end up being a child of or nested inside of this very root `container` element. So, you need to reference that `container` like so:

```
ReactDOM.render(<Sidebar />, document.querySelector('.container'));
```

So this is saying go find the div and render the App component inside that div.